# Quarkus native with Kafka Streams and Schema Registry

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, quarkus, confluent-schema-registry, graalvm

Quarkus (1.5.0.Final) as native executable works fine with Kafka Streams and Avro Schema Registry.
But in case of a Kafka streams consuming a topic with Avro Serdes, if a new event is added, there is an exception:

The kafka-streams-avro-serde library try to reach (via REST API) the Schema Registry with the schema added.
This exception below occured: (This works fine in Qaurkus + JVM)

Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error registering Avro schema: {"type":"record","name":"siteconf","namespace":"test","fields":[{"name":"id","type":["null","string"],"default":null},{"name":"site","type":["null","string"],"default":null},{"name":"configuration","type":["null","string"],"default":null}],"connect.name":"siteconf"}
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Internal Server Error; error code: 500

I don't know how to workaround this problem.
It's very annoying because I think it's the only one problem I've detected in Kafka Streams with Schema Registry.
And I was interrested to adaopt Quarkus instead of Spring Boot/Cloud